# Change separator between maintitle and title in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I've figured out how to change the separator between the title and a subtitle in `biblatex` by using `\subtitlepunct` (as in the entry for Larsen 1907 below), but how can I introduce the same tweak for the separator between a maintitle and a title (as in the entry for Bülbring 1902 below)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{bulbring1902,
    AUTHOR = "Karl D. Bülbring",
    TITLE = "Lautlehre",
    YEAR = "1902",
    LOCATION = "Heidelberg",
    MAINTITLE = "Altenglisches Elementarbuch",
    NUMBER = "4",
    PART = "1",
    PUBLISHER = "Carl Winter's Universitätsbuchhandlung",
    SERIES = "Sammlung germanischer Elementarbücher. I. Reihe: Grammatiken"}
@BOOK{larsen1907,
    AUTHOR = "Amund B. Larsen",
    TITLE = "Kristiania bymål",
    YEAR = "1907",
    LOCATION = "Kristiania",
    PUBLISHER = "Cammermeyers boghandel",
    SUBTITLE = "Vulgærsproget med henblik på den utvungne dagligtale"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{bulbring1902}\nocite{larsen1907}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The punctuation between `maintitle` and `title` (or between `maintitle`, `volume` and `title`) is hard-coded into `biblatex` (you will find the default in `standard.bbx`), so we have to modify the commands that print the `maintitle`.

First we define a new punctuation mark `\maintitlepunct`.

```
\providecommand{\maintitlepunct}{\itshape\addcolon\addspace}
\renewcommand{\maintitlepunct}{\itshape\addcolon\addspace}
```

We can then use it in your macros. The first macro now puts `\maintitlepunct` between the `maintitle` and the `title` (if no volume is given) and the standard `\newunit` between `maintitle` and `volume`/`part` followed by the `title` preceded by `\maintitlepunct`.
The second macro does esentially the same thing, but for `booktitle` instead of `title`.

```
\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+title}{%
  \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}
    {\clearfield{maintitle}%
     \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
     \clearfield{maintitleaddon}}
    {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
        %\newunit\newblock % commented out
        \iffieldundef{volume}
          {\setunit{\maintitlepunct}}% was empty
          {\newunit\newblock% this is new
           \printfield{volume}%
           \printfield{part}%
           \setunit{\addcolon\space}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     %\newunit\newblock % commented out
     \iffieldundef{volume}
       {\setunit{\maintitlepunct}}% was empty
       {\newunit\newblock% this is new
        \printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}%
        \setunit{\addcolon\space}}}%
  \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
  \newunit}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{bulbring1902,
    AUTHOR = "Karl D. Bülbring",
    TITLE = "Lautlehre",
    YEAR = "1902",
    LOCATION = "Heidelberg",
    MAINTITLE = "Altenglisches Elementarbuch",
    NUMBER = "4",
    PART = "1",
    PUBLISHER = "Carl Winter's Universitätsbuchhandlung",
    SERIES = "Sammlung germanischer Elementarbücher. I. Reihe: Grammatiken"}
@BOOK{larsen1907,
    AUTHOR = "Amund B. Larsen",
    TITLE = "Kristiania bymål",
    YEAR = "1907",
    LOCATION = "Kristiania",
    PUBLISHER = "Cammermeyers boghandel",
    SUBTITLE = "Vulgærsproget med henblik på den utvungne dagligtale"}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}

\providecommand{\maintitlepunct}{\itshape\addcolon\addspace}
\renewcommand{\maintitlepunct}{\itshape\addcolon\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+title}{%
  \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}
    {\clearfield{maintitle}%
     \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
     \clearfield{maintitleaddon}}
    {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
        %\newunit\newblock % commented out
        \iffieldundef{volume}
          {\setunit{\maintitlepunct}}% was empty
          {\newunit\newblock% this is new
           \printfield{volume}%
           \printfield{part}%
           \setunit{\addcolon\space}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     %\newunit\newblock % commented out
     \iffieldundef{volume}
       {\setunit{\maintitlepunct}}% was empty
       {\newunit\newblock% this is new
        \printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}%
        \setunit{\addcolon\space}}}%
  \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}
\nocite{bulbring1902,larsen1907,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: This works well. Any particular reason you use ``\providecommand`` followed by ``\renewcommand`` rather than just using ``\newcommand``? The colon separator should be italicized, btw, so I'll edit that in.

Comment: @Sverre I used `\providecommand` just to be on the safe side - though one could argue that `\newcommand` would be better - because it warns if you overwrite, the `\renewcommand` is just there for analogy with `\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}` and in this case obviously superfluous.

Comment: I've edited your code. As mentioned in my comment above, the colon separator should be italicized, but _not_ when there is something in the field ``VOLUME``.